# Debugger.IsAttached only working when launched from visual studio

Tags: c#, debugging

I'm using a timer which is constantly checking if a debugger is attached like this:

```
private void DebuggerCheck_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        //Take action 
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work on external debuggers. When I launch the program through Visual Studio it does return true, but when I attach the Visaul Studio debugger or any other external debuggers like IDA, x64dbg, CheatEngine... it doesn't detect them. Any idea why it wouldn't?

Comment: works fine for me, I can't reproduce it (console application, debug and release mode, started from vs and via explorer, works in every constellation with vs2017 debugger)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [C# Detect if Debugger is Attached](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/670193/csharp-detect-if-debugger-is-attached) the property `Debugger.IsAttached` will only detect managed debuggers (which should include the visual studio debugger of course, thanks @René Vogt). You can use [CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms679280(v=vs.85).aspx) instead, the documentation states:

> The "remote" in CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent does not imply that the debugger necessarily resides on a different computer; instead, it indicates that the debugger resides in a separate and parallel process. Use the IsDebuggerPresent function to detect whether the calling process is running under the debugger.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern bool CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent(IntPtr hProcess, ref bool isDebuggerPresent);
```

> In order to avoid any confusion about `Debugger.IsAttached` and `IsDebuggerPresent` - sorry I didn't mention this earlier in the tip:
>
> `IsDebuggerPresent` = works for any running process and detects native debuggers too
>   `Debugger.IsAttached` = works only for the current process and detects only managed debuggers.

Comment: Interesting, but OP said even the Visual Studio debugger won't work when attached to the running process.

Comment: Hm... that's true... seems like I "fired" to fast :D
That - however - could explain some of the external debuggers though

Comment: Looks like a correct answer to me. There is 77% chance that OP attached VS as native debugger based on list of other debugger they tried..

Comment: @RenéVogt: Attaching VS2017 (15.8.9) as managed debugger does seem to set `Debugger.IsAttached` to true. I did not try a program without I/O or system calls tho. It's not inconceivable that the property setting to true might lag if the thread is in the running state.